# How to pronounce the unstressed е in прише́дшие?

Tags: произношение, ударение, фонетика, редукция-гласных

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology#Unstressed_vowels) says:

> - ...
> - /e/ has merged with /i/ (or /i/ and /ɨ/ if /ɨ/ is considered a phoneme): for instance, лиса́ (lisá) 'fox' and леса́ 'forests' are both pronounced /lʲiˈsa/, phonetically About this sound[lʲɪˈsa].
> - ...

So I expected прише́дшие to sound like [priʃjedʃi**i**], not [priʃjedʃi**je**]. In other words, **the sound of the unstressed e here** should boil from [je] to [i] as per the rule above. Yet, many singers (in fact, this is from the song called Журавли) actually don't pronounce that way; I hear [e] at the end of the word. Can you explain why?

Comment: With the last syllable being stressed it looks like 1) a noun 2) borrowed from a foreign language, probably French.

Comment: teasing out pronunciation from songs is not the most reliable method, because singers tend to enunciate phonemes more clearly which defaults to the way they are written, especially singers from the Soviet era who generally had formal education as vocalists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is justified, in speech **прише́дшие** is indeed pronounced like [pri**ʃ**jedʃi**i**], the final [е] gets reduced, **пришеччыи**

The transcription [priʃjedʃije] is also wrong about pronunсiation of **[д]** which here merges with **[ш]** to form geminated hard **[чч]** or is assimilated to form a combination **[чш]** and thus is essentially not pronounced.

> `Произношение окончания именительного падежа множественного  числа` 
>   прилагательных  и  `причастий`.  В  этой  форме  орфографические 
>   окончания прилагательных и `причастий` **-ые**, **-ие** `по старомосковской норме`  произносятся  как **[ыи]**, **[ии]**:  **`кра′сн[ыи] (красные)`**,  **`но′в[ыи] (новые)`**, **`си′н[ии] (синие)`**, **`раскры′т[ыи] (раскрытые)`**, **`чита′ющ[ии] (читающие)`**. `Вариантной  нормой` современного русского  литературного  языка  является произношение  орфографических сочетаний **-ые**, **-ие**  как **[ииь]**, **[ыиь]**:
>   **`кра′сн[ыиь] (красные)`**, **`но′в[ыиь] (новые)`**, **`си′н[ииь] (синие)`**, **`раскры′т[ыиь] (раскрытые)`**, **`чита′ющ[ииь] (читающие)`**.

<sup>*Мусатов В.Н. — «Русский язык. Фонетика. Фонология. Орфоэпия. Графика. Орфография»*, p. 175</sup>

> В сочетаниях **тш**, **дш** на месте букв **т** и **д** в беглой речи
>   произносится звук **[т]** с некоторым фрикативным шипящим элементом, т. е. по существу **твердая аффриката [ч]**: **`приве′[чш]ый (приведший)`**,
>   **`обве[чш]а′лый (обветшалый)`**, **`мла′[чш]ий (младший)`**, **`по[чш]у′бой (под шубой)`**.

<sup>[*Аванесов - «Русское литературное произношение»*](http://archive.is/nPG08), p. 188</sup>

---

[**Examples of `пришедшие` pronunciation**](https://youtu.be/MF9Ji4bHVdc) from [Russian National Corpus' multimedia database](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=murco&sort=gr_tagging&ext=10&nolinks=1&accent=1&ell=1&expand=full&req=%AB%EF%F0%E8%F8%E5%27%E4%F8%E8%E5%BB) where difference between speech and singing is apparent in particular.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Also, that germination rule is interesting. =) I should dig it further.

Comment: I think it depends on the speaker's region of origin. [пришеччыи] sounds very unusual to me. My own pronunciation is similar to [пришэтшиэ].

Comment: true, since [e] is reduced into something amorphous i guess it's difficult to pinpoint how the resulting vowel exactly sounds, it could once sound closer to [ы] and then more like [э] the next time around with the same person

Comment: I assume the latter part(=germination) is Russian-specific, but I see none in [Wikipedia's Russian Phonology page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology). Is there any link that you can cite or quote about that topic?

Comment: I've never seen a book that says it geminates to чч—They all say (aside from your reference) that it becomes тш—Russian and English sources. As a personal aside, the researcher that you referenced isn't considered to be the most accurate. There are much better reference works now.

Comment: but we do not pronounce it as **[тш]** either, you don't hear two distinct sounds, it's a single sound close to hard **[ч]** which Russian officially doesn't have, but which apparently occurs under assimilation, there's almost no sonic difference between geminated hard **[ч]** and the cluster **[чш]** because **[ш]** is always hard in Russian anyway

Comment: I've never seen much use in books on Russian phonetics claiming that `лиса` and `леса` are pronounced identically because they are definitely not. I do understand why this "simplified explanation" is so popular but I would warn any foreigner who is serious about phonetics not to take such claims literally. The two sounds are different, it's just that the difference can't be expressed in Russian letters and requires a very lengthy scientific explanation, which would be TL;DR :) I also do not trust sources that use things like [ииь], [ыиь] - I mean, how on Earth is this supposed to sound?

Comment: @tum_ the transcription [ииь], [ыиь] made me wonder as well, but to be honest i wasn't bothered enough to look deeper into the book to find the list of transcription conventions it uses, i hope they are listed there,  only after we find absence of such a list are we justified in criticizing the author, not for nothing they say 'don't judge a book by its cover'... also does Мусатов make this claim about лиса vs леса?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка yeah, my afterthought was that this might have something to do with the old Russian `ерь` semi-vowel.. Is this book available online or have you typed all that?

Comment: @tum_ i downloaded the book from the Web and copy-pasted the text from the PDF, yes, it's probably ерь, but i haven't managed to locate in the book an explanation of its use in this position, it does seem to signify a reduced final **-э**, that is **-ийэ/ыйэ = -ииь/ыиь**,

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Похоже, что Ь и Ъ общепринятые обозначения для редукции гласных 2-ой степени. См., например последний ответ [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36417/Петербуржская-норма-произношения). Т.е., если книга предназначена филологам, им не нужна отдельная расшифровка этих обозначений. Я, увы, не филолог, так что был не прав. Зато узнал что-то новое.

Comment: @tum_ спасибо за ссылку, хотя  у Мусатова ерь применён не только после мягких согласных, а вообще везде, и более того, после гласных, а вот как например редукция после мягкой согласной транскрибируется ерем в словах **следствие/следствии** [тут](http://fonetica.philol.msu.ru/nn/n54.htm) - **[сл'`ецств'ьь]**

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Being a native speaker, I just pronounced this word a few times to see how I actually pronounce it.

My pronunciation is as follows: пришéдши-и. The part after ''ш'' is as follows: I start pronouncing the ''и'' sound, then it gets quieter, and then loud again, but does not break in the middle. It is like two waves, so to speak.

Pronounce the following word considering it English: pre-shed-shee-ee. This is practically identical to how I pronounce ''пришедшие.'' The syllable ''shee'' is like in ''sheep.''

If I speak fast (i.e., as usual in everyday communications) and use ''пришедшие'' in a sentence, then all vowels practically get swallowed (i.e., are almost not pronounced at all). For example, I pronounce the expression ''пришедшие солдаты'' like ''прьшедшислдаты,'' very fast and barely distinct enough for a native speaker to recognise what I am saying.

Note that there are various dialects in Russia, and mine is the Moscow one, notorious for fast indistinct pronunciation and preference of ''a'' over ''о.''

In other dialects the word ''пришедшие'' may sound differently. To give you an idea how different Russian dialects are, I point to the Novgorod dialect (''новгородский выговор''), in which the city name ''Новгород'' is pronounced exactly as written, with three distinct ''о,'' whereas I pronounce the same word rather as ''Навгрд.''

Comment: `пришéдши-и` - interesting.. `pronouncing the ''и'' sound` - well, is it not the "ы" sound? I can't say "и" after "ш" even if I try hard. What about `лиса́ (lisá) 'fox' and леса́ 'forests' are both pronounced /lʲiˈsa/, phonetically` - is this true for your Moscow dialect? Are the two sounds absolutely identical?

Comment: tum_, pronounce the following word considering it English: pre-shed-shee-ee. This is practically identical to how I pronounce ''пришедшие,'' except that I make the vowel in ''pre'' virtual, intending to pronounce that vowel but not actually pronouncing it. Or, if you will, that vowel is there just for a microsecond. The syllable ''shee'' is like in ''sheep.''

Comment: tum_, yes, лиса́ ('fox') and леса́ ('forests') sound identically in the Moscow dialect, like ''льса.'' To learn to pronounce it properly in the Moscow dialect,  do the following exercise: You first pronounce the word very distinctly in the classical way, i.e., ЛиииииСаааааа, then you make the first vowel shorter, ЛииСаааааа, then even more shorter, ЛиСаааааа, and continue shortening ''и'' until it virtually disappears. Do not change the consonant sounds. (continued below)

Comment: (continuation of the above comment) In the end, the ''и'' sound must be only virtually there, for a microsecond. It is like intending to pronounce it but not really pronouncing, similar to how ''u'' gets virtual in the word ''difficult.'' Then make ''а'' as short as needed, just enough for making a distinct stressed vowel sound. Then relax your lips, tongue, and all muscles involved in making sounds, and pronounce the word with the minimal physical effort. Voila.

Comment: :) You obviously mistook me for a foreigner, which was not my intention at all (and you could check my profile). Anyway, let's hope your exercises help someone else.  Now, if I say 'shee' I have to pronounce English "soft sh' but I don't do English accent when I speak Russian. Similarly, 'льса' is not fair :) What sound do you pronounce when you have to pronounce it - say, in a song or a verse, where you break the rhythm if you drop it.

Comment: In ''пришедшие'' i pronounce the last  ''ш'' as the average between ''ш'' and ''щ'' in my dialect. ''Sheep'' is a good approximation. I do not really hear the classical ''ы'' sound after ''ш'' when I pronounce ''пришедшие''; it is rather something in between ''и'' and ''ы,'' closer to ''и.'' Anyway, such nuances are hard to tell from my Moscow dialect fast indistinct speech, where vowels are barely pronounced at all and serve merely as links between consonants and where ''ш'' and ''щ'' are much closer to each other than in the classical Russian pronunciation.

Comment: If I have to pronounce ''лиса'' or ''леса'' as a two-syllable word in order not to disturb the rhythm of a verse, the first vowel will be pronounced as an indistinct connecting vowel sound, something in between ''и'' and ''е.'' The same applies to ''пировать,'' ''переделать'' and so on. It is just a typical Moscow indistinct unstressed vowel sound connecting consonants.

Comment: Мы, наверное, злоупотребляем терпением модераторов. Я подумываю открыть новый вопрос на [русскоязычном SE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), но сначала надо прошерстить, не обсуждалось ли это уже тысячу раз...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mind the original formal rules of pronunciation. Different regions or groups may have pronunciation specific to them. But they are still accepted, meaning that there is some range of pronunciations which are widely accepted regardless of the officially accepted one. That's right, if you pronounce it as "e", the word would be perfectly recognized as "correct" (also, you may intentionally pronounce it non-oficcially so that it would not sound similar to an almost same sounding word), albeit with the sense of "dialect" or something similar.