# Pronunciation of существительное

Tags: произношение

In Google Translate, in the Wiktionary audio recording and in some Forvo audio recordings of the word "существительное", I am unable to hear the ending E (/iə/ in unstressed syllables like the last one). Is this an usual pronunciation or regionalism? Is it an exception of the pronunciation rules?

Wiktionary: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5

Forvo: https://forvo.com/word/%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/

Comment: This is a duplicate question, actually. A very similar question has been asked here some time this year. I remember taking part in the discussion. The word was "прошедшие" or something close. I'll try to provide a link later on unless someone else beats me (it's notoriously difficult to use SE via the android client).

Comment: Search 'Russian Language' for "How to pronounce the unstressed е in прише́дшие". Can't copy a link to a question in android (and this really pisses me off every time).

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/19473/2104

Comment: Справедливости ради, здесь "-ное", а там "-шие", so it's not exactly a duplicate and most of that discussion is not relevant to this question. Maybe this one was marked as duplicate too early.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I am aware that the pronunciation of non-stressed vowels change. My question is why [je] is not pronounced in [sʊɕːɪstˈvʲitʲɪlʲnəjə] (the pronunciation provided in the Wiktionary link in my question)

Comment: I voted to re-open, not sure how exactly this works here. But generally there is nothing particularly interesting in the question. It (the [j] sound) might be actually pronounced by *some people* and not pronounced by others (by me, for one, and many others). As long as the word remains perfectly recognisable - there is no law that dictates the pronunciation of unstressed syllables. Russian is very different from Spanish, Portuguese or, say, Czech in this regard.